# Calculation of rolling weights with initial weight at the first day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` for `weights` and `returns` and I want to adjust the `weights` based on the returns one day before, except for the initial weights. The basic idea is that the weights are changing based on the returns.

I created an example with the `weights`, `returns` and the preferred `rolling weights`:

```
weights:
            01K W   02K W   03K W   04K W
Dates               
2021-01-01  0.0     0.2     0.3     0.5
2021-01-02  0.0     0.2     0.3     0.5
2021-01-03  0.5     0.2     0.3     0.0
2021-01-04  0.5     0.2     0.3     0.0
2021-01-05  0.5     0.0     0.2     0.3
2021-01-06  0.5     0.0     0.2     0.3

returns:
            01K W   02K W   03K W   04K W
Dates               
2021-01-01  0.01    0.01    -0.03   0.05
2021-01-02  0.02    0.02    0.04    -0.02
2021-01-03  0.03    -0.03   0.01    -0.02
2021-01-04  -0.03   0.01    0.02    0.03
2021-01-05  0.02    0.02    0.01    0.01
2021-01-06  0.01    -0.01   0.03    0.02
```

With these `weights` and `returns`, I try to calculate the `rolling weights` for `01K W` as follows:

- 2021-01-03: 0.5 (initial weight) (ignore return on previous day)
- 2021-01-04: 0.515  = 0.5 * (1+0.03) (0.03=return on 2021-01-03)
- 2021-01-05: 0.4996 = 0.5 * (1+0.03) * (1-0.03)(-0.03=return on 2021-01-04)
- 2021-01-06: 0.5095 = 0.5 * (1+0.03) * (1-0.03) * (1+0.02)(0.02=return on 2021-01-05)

```
rolling_weights:
            01K W   02K W   03K W   04K W
Dates               
2021-01-01  0.0000  0.20000 0.30000 0.500
2021-01-02  0.0000  0.20200 0.29100 0.525
2021-01-03  0.5000  0.20604 0.30264 0.000
2021-01-04  0.5150  0.19986 0.30567 0.000
2021-01-05  0.4996  0.00000 0.20785 0.300
2021-01-06  0.5095  0.00000 0.20993 0.303
```

For reproducibility:

```
import pandas as pd
returns = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06'],
    '01K W':[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, -0.03, 0.02, 0.01], 
    '02K W':[0.01, 0.02, -0.03, 0.01, 0.02, -0.01], 
    '03K W':[-0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03], 
    '04K W':[0.05, -0.02, -0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02]}) 
returns = returns.set_index('Dates')

weights = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06'],
    '01K W':[0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
    '02K W':[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0], 
    '03K W':[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2], 
    '04K W':[0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.3]}) 
weights = weights.set_index('Dates')
```

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply `weights` by partial (i.e. resets every time `weights` are zero) cumprod of `returns` that are zeroed at positions where `weights` are zero, and then shifted 1 position down:

```
weights_new = pd.DataFrame([weights[col]*(returns.where(weights!=0,0).shift(1).fillna(0)+1)[col].groupby(((returns.where(weights!=0,0).shift(1).fillna(0)+1)[col] == 1).cumsum()).cumprod() for col in weights.columns]).T
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it doesn't match exactly my prefered output. For example (2021-01-02/04K W) I try to get 0.525 (=0.5*(1+0.05)) and I think you take the cumulative product over the whole period. Do you know how to adjust it, that we always start with the cumulative product when we assign a new weight?

Comment: I already noticed the mismatches and adjusted my answer, it works for all cases except 04K W because of discontinuity in the middle, probably will look at it later to fix.

Comment: Ah great, yes that already looks quite close to what I try to achieve. Could it be caused by the cumulative product over all periods, which is not reset if we assign a new weight?

Comment: That's exactly it, was just thinking how to implement partial cumprod, in the end did it with groupby, so it works for all cases now. Adjusted the answer. It turned out as a pretty bloated one-liner, but hey, it works.